# Supertype for Option#orElse

Tags: scala

[Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) walks through and builds the `Option` type. It shows, among others, the `orElse` method:

`def orElse[B >: A](ob: => Option[B]): Option[B]`

As the book explains: `The B >: A says that the B type parameter must be a supertype of A.`

Why is it necessary, for `orElse`'s parameterized type to be a supertype of `A`?

Comment: It may be a dupe, but that's a very thoughtful photo.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the fact that it was asked on SO many times, FP in Scala also has a great wiki on GitHub, where this part, orElse method, [explained](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/wiki/Chapter-4:-Handling-errors-without-exceptions#covariance-and-contravariance) in details.